# $x^2 + 2y^2=3^k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are not factor of $3$. Prove that $\forall k \in \mathbb N$ there exists $(x , y)$ that $x^2 + 2y^2 = 3^k$.

I know that $x^2 + 2y^2$ is divisible by $3$ always. But how can we prove that there exists a solution $\forall k \in \mathbb N$? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Yes , but how can we do that?

Comment: Hint:  Think about expressions like $\left(1+\sqrt {-2}\right)^k=\left(a_k+b_k\sqrt {-2}\right)$.

Comment: Well, I think the base case is obvious (can you think of an (x, y) for $x^2+2y^2=3$?).  Note you also need the fact that $x$ and $y$ are not multiples of $3$.  If you work now in mod $3$, and you square $x$ and $y$ what does that mean?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vladovin Are you actually interested in the solutions, I can write some Mathematica code to find them?

Comment: For $k=2n$ you could say $x=3^n$ and $y=0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, you can't, because of "such that both $x$ and $y$ are not factor of $3$" (at least I think that's what that means).

Comment: Sry. I didn’t get the message due to the time-zone.

Comment: @JanEerland Actually, I don’t. But thanks anyway. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use these:**

$1^2+2\cdot1^2=3$

$1^2+2\cdot2^2=3^2$

$(3x)^2+2(3y)^2=3^2(x^2+2 y^2)$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta–Fibonacci_identity

Comment: That's pretty much the whole solution!

Comment: I took out the word **Hint** in deference to the comments